# Select All Rows, Group By

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-by

While using Codeigniter 3, I'm trying to select all records from table "X" while trying to group them by column "Y" as shown below:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from("X");
$this->db->where(array('is_active' => 1));
$this->db->group_by('Y');
```

However, this retrieves only one record for each group....  any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Group combines rows. If you want to list them in order of column Y, then you want `order by`.

Comment: That's the whole point of grouping results together.

Comment: What do you expect from a group by .. ?  show a proper data sample and the expected result.. or you need  order by?

Comment: scaisEdge.. I was hoping to find a simple query to select all the rows and group them accordingly...   10 rows for group A, 5 rows for group B.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern :

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('X');
    $this->db->where('is_active', 1);
    $this->db->group_by('Y');
    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query_result->result();
    return $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

use $this->db->get()->result_array() and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Thanks, but It only returns one record for each group....   eg, if group "1" has 10 records, and group "2" has 5 records, I need the query to return all rows for each record.